# Manage Logs on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, logging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Centralized Log Monitoring](https://serverfault.com/questions/65209/centralized-log-monitoring)

is there any good solution for Ubuntu Server to collect and view all kinds of logs in one central web interface?
Or which approach is used by professional administrators to handle logs?
The only thing I found on Google is command line stuff or ugly Windows or Java applications.

Any help appreciated.

Regards
Nils

Comment: "professional administrators" use command line.  `grep` rocks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) and their [Splunk for *nix](http://splunk-base.splunk.com/apps/22314/splunk-for-unix-and-linux) application? If your volumes are low it's free.

Comment: Looks good...since it is only for PHP Development Server there won't be more than 500MB logs.

Comment: I have to admit I'm one of their top customers and utterly love the product for far more than just what you get free, an it can get very expensive if you log a lot, but I can't make any higher recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

The Best log analysis (free) available are ELSA and LogZilla.

http://code.google.com/p/enterprise-log-search-and-archive/

http://www.logzilla.pro/

Answer (score 2):

Check out the open source self-hostable -- http://graylog2.org/