# F5 Load Balancer and SIEM

Tags: syslog, f5-big-ip

I am looking for information on whether F5 can forward syslog info to a SIEM such as arclight or Qradar.

I have heard that you can only send unencrypted traffic on port 80 but you cant forward anything encrypted. Is this true. Has anyone else ran into this issue.

Comment: Are you intending to have the F5 Big-IP send it's own log data to the SIEM, or are you looking to have the Big-IP load balance syslog traffic?

Answer (score 0):

F5 BIG-IP uses syslog-ng for it's basic logging so it will be reliant on [mutual auth via TLS](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/54#TOPIC-956591) or or some [stunnel method](https://serverfault.com/questions/20840/how-would-you-send-syslog-securely-over-the-public-internet).

**[Per F5's documentation](https://techdocs.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/tmos-concepts-11-5-0/11.html)(bottom of page):**

> "If you want to ensure that the Syslog-ng messages being logged
>   remotely are encrypted, you must first establish a secure tunnel."

This assumes you're only going to use vanilla syslog-ng included on the system.

F5 BIG-IP usually integrates into SIEMs with the High Speed Logging (HSL) which instead provides events including near-real time events like security attacks and other time-sensitive logging needs. BIG-IP includes security features and syslog was not appropriate for the event traffic.

F5 BIG-IP [Hight Speed Logging](https://techdocs.f5.com/en-us/bigip-14-0-0/external-monitoring-of-big-ip-systems-implementations-14-0-0/about-logging.html) does support secure remote logging.

Most major SIEM vendors will also include specific on how to integrate with F5 BIG-IP.

If you have any additional info, comment here and I can update my answer accordingly.